# JVM makes a full GC then there is no more system memory left

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

i have a Java web application,when the JVM makes a FGC,there is no more memory left,then swap will be used, and the load is growing fast. And i can't undersatand why,anybody could help me?

Comment: Profile it? JvisualVM

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have set the maximum heap size `(-Xmx)` high enough that the JVM doesn't have any memory left for garbage collection.  As such, the system runs out of RAM and starts swapping to disk.

You can begin by either reducing `-Xmx` or adding some RAM to your system and figure what's making your app consume so much memory.

Comment: i have 5G memory,and -Xmx i set to 2048m , so there is 3G left。

Comment: But it's possible that other apps on your system are using more than 3G.  You'd know best about what's running on your system.

Comment: Is there a way to find out "which process used the most memory between a certain time in linux platform" ?

Comment: Your best bet is to monitor system variables.  For monitoring the JVM, you can consider using `jconsole` that is bundled with the JDK.

Answer (score 1):

Either your Java heap size is too low for the [working set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_set) of data you are processing, or you have a [memory leak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) which is consuming the memory that could otherwise be used for useful processing.

Your first point of attack could be to use a [profiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29) to understand exactly what is consuming memory.  [JVisualVm](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) is a somewhat bare-bones but competent profiler.  From there, you can make decisions about whether you need to allocate more memory (via `-Xmx` VM arguments), fix memory leaks, or make algorithmic improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Enable Full GC logging so you can see what is happening in your Heap.

- Compute Live Data Set, Allocation Rate, and Promotion Rate. This will tell you if you need a bigger Heap or if your eg. Young Gen is too small, or if your Survivor spaces are overflowing, etc.
- Compute total GC time, it should be <5% of total running time.

Use `-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+LogVMOutput -XX:LogFile=jvm.log -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xloggc:gc.log -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -showversion`